# Subselect to Grab Most Recent Record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a view in SQL server that is used to download data through a connection into Access. The purpose is to sort through all the records in the company db and my own, finding the record that was most recently entered and that is the record for the employee that is downloaded. When working properly it should only download about 65000 records, but it is downloading every employees record no matter when it happened. the MEETING END DATE field is the timestamp field that indicates when the record was entered. Someone recommend I build a sub select in it but sub queries are not my strong suit and I am having a hard time figuring out the proper way to do so. The code is below

```
SELECT 
   AC.REG_NR, AC.DIS_NR, AC.GEMSID, AC.TMS_ID, AC.EMP_NA, AC.EMP_SEX_TYP_CD, 
   AC.EMP_EOC_GRP_TYP_CD, AC.DIV_NR, AC.CTR_NR, 
   AC.JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE, AC.JOB_GRP_CD, AC.Job_Function, AC.Job_Group, 
   AC.Meeting_Readiness_Rating, AC.Manager_Readiness_Rating, CD.Employee_ID, 
   CD.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Expr1, CD.Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Expr2, 
   CD.Meeting_End_Date, CD.EmployeeFeedback, 
   CD.DevelopmentForEmployee1, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee2, 
   CD.DevelopmentForEmployee3, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee4, 
   CD.DevelopmentForEmployee5, 
   CD.Justification, CD.Changed, CD.Notes
FROM  
   dbo.AC_Source AS AC 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   (SELECT 
       EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, 
       MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, 
       ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
       logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, 
       DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
       DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes
   FROM   
       dbo.AC_CDData_1

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
       Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating, Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
       Meeting_End_Date, '' AS EmployeeFeedback, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee1, 
       '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee2, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee3,
       '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee4, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee5, 
       '' AS Justification,  '' AS Changed, '' AS Notes
   FROM  
       dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
   WHERE 
       (Plan_Year = '2013')) AS CD ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.Employee_ID
```

It basically needs to search the employee IDs and find the max MEETING END DATE for each employee

Comment: You probably don't want to `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as that would give you all records from `AC`, regardless if they match what's coming back from `CD` or not. Simply use `JOIN` and you might be set. Reading a bit deeper into it, well.. not really, but the remark stands that you want `JOIN` imho.

Comment: But the thing is, one table contains employee information the other one does, and not every employee is on that table. Which is why I used left outer join because even if they are not on the one table I need their employee data anyway.

Comment: I understand `LOGDATE` is the timestamp column, but with what other field(s) in `AC_CDData_1` do you need to combine it to ensure you only get 1 record ? Also, do you want to include `Meeting_End_Date` from `TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating` in the filtering ? And what would the fields be there to make sure the combination is unique ?

Comment: I need all the records listed for the end result, the Meeting End Date is what I should have said, not logdate. Meeting End Date is the timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok,

If I've understood the question correctly, you should be able to accomplish what you're trying to do by using a RANK Window function.  I've rewritten the query quite a bit to eliminate a lot of the selection criteria which is primarily noise in regards to the core logic you're trying to get to:

```
SELECT Blah1
FROM  dbo.AC_Source AS AC 
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Blah2 FROM 
    (
        SELECT Blah2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmployeeID ORDER BY Meeting_End_Date DESC) AS RowNum
        FROM
        (
            SELECT Blah2
            FROM   dbo.AC_CDData_1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT Blah2
            FROM  dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
            WHERE (Plan_Year = '2013')
         ) AS InnerSelect
    ) AS CD
    WHERE RowNum = 1
)
ON AC.TMS_ID = CD.Employee_ID
```

So what's happening here is that the employee records within the InnerSelect are being grouped by EmployeeID, then ranked in order of Meeting_End_Date within that partitioning.  The "WHERE RowNum = 1" clause outside of the inner select is saying that you will only take records that rank #1 in that partitioned, ranked set of employees.

I may not have gotten the syntax exactly right as it's a bit tough to test without having your tables (and I don't have the time right now to make them), but the idea should work for what you're looking to accomplish.

Comment: Oh, I should add that I also made the outermost join an inner join as I don't believe that you truly needed an outer join, unless I slightly misunderstood your criteria.

Comment: I am trying to write this but I am not sure I am doing it properly. Let me know when you have a second and I can edit the above code to reflect the edits you suggested that I tried to make.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's rather ugly and I fear performance will be 'below expectations', without anything to test this on this is going to be my best shot :

```
;WITH CD 
    AS (SELECT EmployeeID AS Employee_ID, MeetingReadinessLevel AS Meeting_Readiness_Rating, ManagerReadinessLevel AS Manager_Readiness_Rating, 
                                logdate AS Meeting_End_Date, EmployeeFeedback, DevelopmentForEmployee1, DevelopmentForEmployee2, DevelopmentForEmployee3, 
                                DevelopmentForEmployee4, DevelopmentForEmployee5, Justification, Changed, Notes
                FROM   dbo.AC_CDData_1

                UNION ALL
                SELECT Employee_ID, Meeting_Readiness_Rating, Manager_Readiness_Rating, Meeting_End_Date, '' AS EmployeeFeedback, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee1, 
                                '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee2, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee3, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee4, '' AS DevelopmentForEmployee5, '' AS Justification, 
                                '' AS Changed, '' AS Notes
                FROM  dbo.TMS_Data_Latest_Career_Meeting_Rating
                WHERE (Plan_Year = '2013')
        ),
        MAXCD
    AS (SELECT Employee_ID, Last_Meeting_End_Date = MAX(Meeting_End_Date)
        FROM CD
        GROUP BY Employee_ID)

SELECT AC.REG_NR, AC.DIS_NR, AC.GEMSID, AC.TMS_ID, AC.EMP_NA, AC.EMP_SEX_TYP_CD, AC.EMP_EOC_GRP_TYP_CD, AC.DIV_NR, AC.CTR_NR, 
            AC.JOB_CLS_CD_DSC_TE, AC.JOB_GRP_CD, AC.Job_Function, AC.Job_Group, AC.Meeting_Readiness_Rating, AC.Manager_Readiness_Rating, CD.Employee_ID, 
            CD.Meeting_Readiness_Rating AS Expr1, CD.Manager_Readiness_Rating AS Expr2, CD.Meeting_End_Date, CD.EmployeeFeedback, 
            CD.DevelopmentForEmployee1, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee2, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee3, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee4, CD.DevelopmentForEmployee5, 
            CD.Justification, CD.Changed, CD.Notes
FROM  dbo.AC_Source AS AC 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ( SELECT CD.* 
                        FROM CD
                        JOIN MAXCD 
                        ON MAXCD.Employee_ID = CD.Employee_ID
                        AND MAXCD.Last_Meeting_End_Date = CD.Meeting_End_Date ) FLTRD

                ON AC.TMS_ID = FLTRD.Employee_ID
```

Comment: I am not sure what the above is supposed to look like. What is the top portion for? Is that all supposed to be one code?

Comment: The top part is a `CTE` (aka Common Table Expression) and is just a different way of writing sub-queries. Given the /complexitiy/ of the sub-query I thought it to be more readable to have it separately on top. But, yes, this all is just 1 query.